# MySQL IN operator not working in a stored procedure setting

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a stored procedure that basically constructs a SQL based on the parameters passed to the proc. One of the parameter is of type TEXT (passed from the app side as an ArrayList) and the values in this particular parameter affects a great deal in construction of the SQL.

I'm trying to implement branching conditions based on whether a String "MACU" is in the list or not. In a nutshell, the proc is something like:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `someReport`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `someReport`(IN group_id_list TEXT, IN encounter_type_list TEXT)

BEGIN

SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, 'SELECT * FROM beneficiary b');

IF encounter_type_list IS NOT NULL THEN
     IF("MACU" IN (encounter_type_list) > 0) THEN
           SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, ' JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = b.id ');
     END IF;

     IF ("MACU" IN (encounter_type_list) <= 0) THEN
           SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, ' JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = b.id ');
     END IF;
END IF;


SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,' WHERE b.group_id IN ',group_id_list);

-- PREPARE stmt3 FROM @QUERY;
-- EXECUTE stmt3;
-- DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3; 


SELECT "MACU", encounter_type_list , "MACU" IN (encounter_type_list);


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

At the moment, although `encounter_type_list` contains "MACU", I always end up in the second IF statement. For instance  `CALL someReport( '(1,2,3)','("MACU","ABC")');` prints the following output:

```
|  MACU  |  encounter_type_list  |   "MACU" IN (encounter_type_list)  |
   MACU       ("MACU","ABC")                        0
```

I fail to understand why the portion `"MACU" IN (encounter_type_list)` returns 0 despite the desired string being present in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encounter_type_list` is a string but `IN` statement is for sets so you end up on the second IF because you have always ONE string item in a set `"MACU","ABC"`.

You should use any string search function - for example [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

```
   IF(INSTR(encounter_type_list,'"MACU"') > 0) THEN
```

or use the following `encounter_type_list` parameter format:

```
CALL someReport( '(1,2,3)','MACU,ABC');
```

and [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to check it in IF statement:

```
 IF(FIND_IN_SET('MACU',encounter_type_list)> 0) THEN
```

Comment: After going thru a similar question on SO, I did try FIND_IN_SET() and it did work but for some reason I can't use that. The INSTR() function is the perfect one. Thank you very much!!